# Simple code to handle JNI exceptions

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'd like to have a nice, tidy way of expressing the following java code as JNI:

```
try {
    SomeMethod ();
}
catch (ExceptionType1 e) {
    SomeAction ();
}
catch (ExceptionType2 e) {
    SomeAction ();
}
catch (ExceptionType3 e) {
    SomeAction ();
}
```

Is there a tidy JNI patter for doing this?  At present, I have this:

```
java_class = (*env)->FindClass (env, EXCEPTION_CLASS_NAME);
if (java_class == NULL) {
    *error_type_ref = ERROR_TYPE_FATAL;
    *exception_code_ref = EU_StrSprintf ("Class not found: %s", EXCEPTION_CLASS_NAME);
    cleanup ();
}
if ((*env)->IsInstanceOf (env, exception, java_class)) {
    SomeAction ();
    cleanup ();
}
```

And, of course, this reoccurs for each exception so handled.  There has to be a better way.  Any recommendations?  I'm not interested in porting all of my existing code over to JNA, so I'd like a pattern that can be implemented home-grown, so to speak.

Comment: are you using C or C++ for your JNI code?

Comment: scratch that, I see you're just using plain C.  FWIW, my own experience of JNI showed me that using C++ objects in RAII pattern helps a lot with JNI, e.g. it makes it easier to automatically cleanup when things go out of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment on C vs C++.

I'd try something like this in C++ (nb: *completely untested, and probably doesn't compile as is!*)

```
class JavaClass {

    private:
        jclass cls;
        JNIEnv *env;

    public:
        JavaClass(JNIEnv *env, const char *className) {
            this.env = env;
            cls = env->FindClass(className);
            // handle errors
        }

        ~JavaClass() {
            env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);
        }

        bool isInstanceOf(jobject obj) {
            return env->IsInstanceOf(obj, cls);
        }
};
```

The client code would then look something like:

```
JavaClass ext1(env, "ExceptionType1");
JavaClass ext2(env, "ExceptionType2");
JavaClass ext3(env, "ExceptionType3");

SomeMethod();

if (ex = env->ExceptionOccurred()) {
    if (ext1.isInstanceOf(ex)) {
        doSomething();
    } else if (ext2.isInstanceOf(ex)) {
        doSomething();
    } else if (ext3.isInstanceOf(ex)) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

(Note that the semantics of this `isInstanceOf()` function are bass-ackwards - in this one it's "`class.instanceof(object)`", instead of "`object instanceof class`").

Comment: It's obviously a nice solution, rendered useless by my programming language being C :)

Comment: oh well, you can't please everyone :)

Answer (score -1):

> There has to be a better way

Template pattern, may be?